# performance issue while reading from proxy

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

Tried searching for this but couldn't find anything specific.

```
public abstract class ProxyAdapter : FinancialClient,IProxyAdapter
{
    public ProxyAdapter(string endpointConfigurationName) :base(endpointConfigurationName) 
    {

    }

    public string ServiceURL { get { return base.Endpoint.Address.Uri.AbsoluteUri; } }
    ....
}
```

This is a snippet of my proxy to a SOAP-based service that I have added to my WCF application (.net 4.7.2). The Reference.cs file containing the FinancialClient class is quite big (some 160k lines).

When I try to read the ServiceUrl, it's taking about 2 seconds in the overall call; commenting this line reduces the call duration by about 2 seconds.

Why is it so expensive to read the url this way? Are there any alternates?

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Usually the first call takes more time because in that call the Channel Factory is instantiated and prepared ready for the communication and that costs time. The created Channel Factory will be cached and reused in subsequent calls and so the time will be less.

Comment: @DingPeng, I would've been fine if it happened only the first time, but this is happening for every call. Since the ServiceBehavior is set to PerSesssion on the service class, I'm guessing it takes that additional time on every call to instantiate the ChannelFactory. I wanted to know  if there was some other 'gotcha' I was missing.

Comment: Do you destroy the channel after calling the service?